# knockout mapping functions in child objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been working on this since last week, and I'm stuck.

I've got a 3 tier object, and I just can't seem to get any functions to work except on the top tier.  I'm sure it's my mapping, because I downloaded knockout context debugger and I can't see the functions I create in the child objects, but I can see top level functions in the parent object fine.

Edited to add a fiddle:

Made a fiddle.  At https://jsfiddle.net/cqmgwyd8/90/

```
var BottomSectionViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
// BottomSection is also a collection inside MiddleSectionData
var MiddleSectionMapping = {
    'MiddleSectionData': {
        key: function (MiddleSection) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(MiddleSection.SectionId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new MiddleSectionViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
}

var MiddleSectionViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, MiddleSectionMapping, self);

    self.MiddleSectionFunction = function () {
        alert("hi from the middlesection data. Unfortunately this doesn't even show up when I look at the knockout context debugger, and doesn't run.");
    }.bind(this);
}



var MainViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, MiddleSectionViewModel, self);

    self.selectedTab = ko.observable(1);

    //Set href value of element
    self.selected = ko.observable(null);

    //initial set to show first tabpanel when loading page
    self.init = ko.observable(1);

    //Get href value og element
    self.getHref = function () {
        var target;
        var element = event.target.hash;
        target = element.substr(1);
        return target;
    };

    //Show Tabpanel
    self.showBlock = function () {
        console.log("setting the block");
        var target = self.getHref();
        self.selected(target);
        self.init(2);
    };
    self.TopSectionFunction = function () {
        alert("this one shows if I use click:$parent.TopSectionFunction ");
    }
};

function uncomment(fn){
  return fn.toString().split(/\/\*\n|\n\*\//g).slice(1,-1).join();
}

var data = {
  "Miscdata1": true,
  "Miscdata2": "Bob Markup",
  "Miscdata3": "2018-01-04T09:15:35.0825342-06:00",
  "MiddleSectionData": [
    {
      "BottomSectionName": "bottom1",
      "BottomSectionData": [
        {
          "SectionId": 1,
          "Data1": 1,
          "Data2": 0,
          "Data3": true,
          "Data4": 0
        },
        {
          "SectionId": 2,
          "Data1": 1,
          "Data2": 0,
          "Data3": true,
          "Data4": 0
        }
      ],
      "SectionId": 1
    },
    {
      "BottomSectionName": "bottom2",
      "BottomSectionData": [
        {
          "SectionId":  1,
          "Data1": 1,
          "Data2": 0,
          "Data3": true,
          "Data4": 0
        },
        {
          "SectionId": 2,
          "Data1": 1,
          "Data2": 0,
          "Data3": true,
          "Data4": 0
        }
      ],
      "SectionId": 1
    },
    {
      "BottomSectionName": "bottom3",
      "BottomSectionData": [
        {
          "SectionId": 1,
          "Data1": 1,
          "Data2": 0,
          "Data3": true,
          "Data4": 0
        },
        {
          "SectionId": 2,
          "Data1": 1,
          "Data2": 0,
          "Data3": true,
          "Data4": 0
        }
      ],
      "SectionId": 1
    }
  ]
};

console.log("test");
var viewModel = new MainViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Show us an example of the data you're constructing `MainViewModel` with. You can create an interactive stack snippet by editing your question. Make sure to include knockout (from the dropdown) and the [mappin plugin](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/knockout.mapping) (in that order).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I updated the jsfiddle.

The problem was where I was setting self = this.

Changing it to:

```
var self = options.data;
```

and moving it to the mapping function fixed it.

edit: Actually, turned out I was having an issue with scope.  I hadn't had var in front of it before.